# Gradle repo from gitlab?

Tags: gradle, repository

I have a private gitlab repository.
In gitlab I have published a library as a JAR file. This lib will be used by two other applications. How can I make the gradle build scripts use my private gitlab to load this dependency?

Comment: What is published to the gitlab? JAR files or source files?

Comment: JAR files are published in gitlab

Comment: Under what URL address?

Comment: URL of my repo? git@gitlab.kd.ru:mylib/mylib.git

Comment: What are you truing to achieve? Do you want to define a dependency to such JARs? Under which URL address is the JAR file accessible?

Comment: I want to include my lib from my repo in to another app as dependency

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK this is not directly supported, so you can:

1. Download the file to file system and use the file system dependency
2. setup a custom Ivy resolver
3. hack into [ResolutionStrategy](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html)